# Edit text in text box from macro

Tags: ms-word

I would have thought this would be straightforward, but I can't get it to work (and I could really save myself a lot of work if I could; I am admittedly not a Word macro wizard).

I have a Word doc with a bunch of text blurbs.  I've defined a custom Text Box and added it to the Text Box Gallery.  Now I want to place a Text Box by each blurb, then move the blurb into the Text Box.  And I was hoping to define a macro to automate it somewhat (i.e., I select the blurb text manually, then run a macro that cuts the blurb, moves the cursor into the Text Box right above it, and pastes the blurb there).

It seems to be the 'move into the Text Box' part that is the hurdle.  I can do it manually, from the keyboard, with these steps:

- (with the cursor positioned just to the left of the Text Box) shift-right-arrow (which selects the Text Box)
- F2 (which places the cursor in the text box for editing)

But trying to record a macro that replicates this doesn't work.  The code for the recorded macro ends up looking like this:

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 2")).Select
```

When I run this macro in the debugger, the first statement does, in fact, select the Text Box that the cursor was near when the macro started.

Unfortunately, the second statement not only doesn't move the editing cursor inside that Text Box (like the F2 key does manually), it actually selects a different Text Box (the first one in the document).

I notice that if I view the Selection pane (alt-F10), it displays the Text Boxes I have in the document, and they all have the same name ("Text Box 2").  So I imagine that's part of the problem.  (Wouldn't Word give each Text Box a unique name?)  But it also seems to be the case that I can't find any macro code to move the editing cursor into the currently selected Text Box (is there a SetFocus or something similar?)

Surely this must be possible?  :-/

Thanks.

/John

Answer (score 0):

I know this is stupidly esoteric, but in case anyone was interested, I figured out my own answer.  Here is the macro code that did it:

```
Selection.Cut
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
```

The tricks are:

1) As for the problem of not operating on the right Text Box:  Word threw me off when I tried to define the macro with the Macro Recorder, by inserting the `ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 2")).Select` statement (selecting by *name* wasn't working, because all the Text Boxes have the same name).  But the Text Box is *already* selected (it can be accessed through the `Selection.ShapeRange` object), so it doesn't *need* to be selected again anyway.

2) To move the editing cursor inside the Text Box:  Select on the TextRange object `(Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select).`

I don't think it was going to work to try to define this by Macro Recording; recording just wasn't doing the right thing.  I had to muck with it by hand.

To anyone who may have given this any thought, thanks!

/John